# Get coordinates/limits of AnchoredText

Tags: python, matplotlib

I set up a figure with multiple axes, where some axes have an AnchoredText. I want to add a ConnectionPatch to connect one axis to an AnchoredText in another axis. While I can get the limits of the axis, I'm not sure if something similar can be done for an AnchoredText.

I have looked through the properties of AnchoredText, [Offsetbox](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetBox), and [Artist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist), and have tried a couple of methods but haven't found anything that gives me anything close to what I'm looking for. At best, I can only guess, although I want to be able to code this in a way in which it can be done dynamically.